# What is wrong with my Copy Constructor?

Tags: c++, class, constructor, copy

Why does it crash when I get to the copy constructor function?

In the copy procedure that you will find in my class definitions, I'm making sure that the Queue that will be created as a copy of some other original Queue is empty before copying begins: let's say Queue q1 is not empty and I want to turn q1 into q2. I want to empty the contents of q1 before copying the contents of q2 to q1..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cassert>

using namespace std;

class Dnode
{
    public:
       Dnode(int);
       int  n;
       Dnode*   l, *r;
};

Dnode::Dnode(int tx)
{
    n = tx;
    l = r = NULL;
}

class Queue // reminder: insertions at the rear, deletions at the front
{
    public:
       Queue();
       void enqueue(int x);
       int dequeue(void);
       bool empty(void) const;
       void display(void) const;
       Queue(const Queue&); //copy constructor

    private:
       Dnode*   front, *back;
       void copy(Dnode*);
       void free();

};

Queue::Queue()
{
    front = back = NULL;
}


void Queue::enqueue(int x)
{
    Dnode*  d = new Dnode(x);
    if (empty())
        front = back = d;
    else
    {
        back->r = d;
        d->l = back;
        back = d;
    }
}

int Queue::dequeue(void)
{
    assert(! empty());
    Dnode*  temp = front;
    front = front->r;
    if (front == NULL)
        back = NULL;
    else    front->l = NULL;
    int x = temp->n;
    delete temp;
    return x;
}


bool Queue::empty(void) const
{
    return front == NULL;
}

void Queue::display(void) const
{
    for (Dnode* d = front; d != NULL; d = d->r)
        cout << d->n << " ";
    cout << endl;
}

void Queue::copy(Dnode* dn) // "dn" will be "Front" of Queue being copied
{                           // this procedure will be called in Copy Constructor  
    Dnode* temp=front;      // found underneath this procedure
    while(front!=back)      
    {                       
        front=front->r;
        delete temp;
        temp=front;
    }

    delete temp;

    front=back=temp=NULL;

    if(dn!=NULL)
    {
        while(dn->r!=NULL)
        {
            enqueue(dn->n);
            dn=dn->r;
        }
        enqueue(dn->n);
    }
}

Queue::Queue(const Queue& x)
{
    copy(x.front);
}

int main()
{
    Queue   q;
    if (q.empty()) cout << "q empty" << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) q.enqueue(i);

    q.display();

    int x = q.dequeue();

    cout << "x is " << x << endl;

    q.display();

    Queue q1(q); //<----program crashes when we get here

    q1.display();
}
```

Comment: Why are you deleting if you are copying?  There is no need to free memory during your copy.  In fact you should be allocating memory in the new instance of Queue to hold the copy.

Comment: You're using and deleting uninitialized pointers all over the place...

Comment: Emptying the Queue that will become a copy f some other Queue may be unnecessary as you say, but that shouldn't be the reason the program crashes right? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're confusing a copy constructor with an assignment operator.  In an assignment operator, you have to delete the current queue and replace it with a copy of the second parameter.  But this is a copy constructor.  There is no current queue.  Your members are uninitialized.  So when you begin by trying to delete the existing queue, you're messing with uninitialized pointers.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to initialize `back` and `front` in your copy constructor.

```
void Queue::copy(Dnode* dn) // "dn" will be "Front" of Queue being copied
{   
  Dnode* temp=front;      // found underneath this procedure
  while(front!=back)      
  {                       
      front=front->r;
      delete temp;
      temp=front;
  }
```

The while loop is then acting randomly, as `front` is unitialized, and causes the crash.

Comment: I am assuming that front and back have values when calling the copy procedure but I cannot possibly know what these are. By the way, I'm sure you are all right about the uninitialised pointers, it's just that I somehow get confused when it comes to the copy constructor...

Comment: @user1073400 You can't `delete` something that wasn't `new`d, it's undefined behaviour. But that's what you're doing in your copy constructor.

Comment: @user1073400: your copy member function is fine. The thing is, when you are calling `Queue q1(q);`, the object `q1` you create has random values as for `front` and `back` since the constructor it was created with did not initialize them. In turn, `front` is (probably) not null and different from back.

Comment: @jrok: the crash may even occur on the line right before the `delete`: `front=front->r;` calling `r` and passing it an invalid pointer as `this`.

Comment: hmm... if in main() I type smth like " Queue q1; " won't that initialise its pointers to NULL according to the default constructor? And what if I then use the "q1(q);" ??

Comment: @user1073400: `Queue q1;` will construct `q1` using the default constructor. `Queue q1(q);` will construct `q1` using the copy constructor: in that case, the default constructor is not called.

Comment: what I mean is that if I use the default constructor for q1 first, its pointers will no be uninitialised so I can later use the copy constructor to make q1 a copy of q.. Just a naive thought by a newbie...

Comment: @user1073400: the first part of your sentence makes sense. If you use the default constructor to create q1, then its pointers will be initialized. Now the second part doesn’t make sense: you cannot use a copy constructor on an object that has already been created. You could use your member function `copy()`, and that would work.

Comment: You are right Victor, check out my reply to jrok.. I was confusing copy constructors with assignment operators, thanks for enlightening me guys and sorry for wasting your time! :)

Comment: @user1073400: helping out is always a pleasure, we’ve been through that too :) good luck

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize your front and back pointers to null, then loop through the source `Queue x` grab each Dnode and enqueue it to the new Queue.

Comment: what if my "new" Queue is not empty afterall and I want to turn it into a copy of Queue x?

Comment: The you wouldn't be using your copy constructor. To accomplish what you ask, you'd need to drain the Queue first, then invoke a corrected flavor of copy().

Comment: @user1073400 How could your "new" queue possibly contain anything? While your copy *constructor* is running, the object is not even fully constructed yet, it's being built anew, from scratch. Perhaps you're confusing copy constructor with assignment operator?

Comment: @jrok Bingo! :) I believe that's what I've been confusing the whole time. I thought that a copy constructor constructs a copy of some Queue Qx and that it was possible to use an already existing Queue Qy to turn that into a copy of Qx.. Wow.. Good one right? :)